# extends javascript function inherits array

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code shown below

```
function extends(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function() {
    };
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

function Parent() {
    this.cardArray = [];
}

function Child() {

}
```

then I call

```
extends(Child , Parent);  
var a=new Child();
```

it reports

```
 a.cardArray is undefined
```

Your comment welcome

Comment: Did you ever define `cardArray` in your code?

Comment: @SimonM: It's in `Parent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues there:

First, you can't use `extends` as a function name (unless you use strict mode and only run the code in environments that support strict mode). It's a reserved word in loose mode. (It's not currently *used* and isn't likely to be, but it's reserved.)

The second, and more sigificant, is that you haven't *called* `Parent` anywhere, and so naturally that property has never been added to the object. You need to call `Parent` from within `Child` to get the things it sets up, and you need to do it such that `this` is correct within the call to `Parent`. We can do that via `Function#call`, which lets us call a function specifying what `this` should be (in our case, we want it to be the same as `this` within the call to `Child`):

```
function Child (){

    Parent.call(this);
}
```

So in total, and with the incorrect (but harmless) semicolons removed, and with the `extends` changed to something that isn't reserved, and with the indentation made consistent, we get:

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ohugip/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ohugip/1/edit)

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {

    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

function Parent (){

    this.cardArray=[]; 
}

function Child (){

    Parent.call(this);
}

extend(Child, Parent);

var a = new Child();

console.log("typeof a.cardArray = " + typeof a.cardArray);
```

...which shows "typeof a.cardArray = object", which is correct.

---

Note that truly effective JavaScript inheritance requires (for now) a fair bit of plumbing. You have a lot of it there, but not all of it. (Calls to parent methods are awkward, for instance.) I've done a [very small library called `Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) that does all the plumbing for you, FWIW.